# How do I create a loop that generates future dates based on different frequencies and intervals until a specified end date?

Tags: sql-server, loops, date, if-statement, while-loop

I have a data set that appears like this:

| next_generation_date | procedure | interval | frequency |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-17 00:00:00.000 | Clean Restroom | 1 | day |
| 2021-01-17 00:00:00.000 | Vacuum | 2 | week |
| 2021-02-01 00:00:00.000 | Inspect Fire Extinguisher | 3 | month |
| 2021-10-01 00:00:00.000 | Test Generator | 1 | year |

My goal is to generate multiple date rows for each **procedure** by going off of the **next_generation_date**, **interval** and **frequency** columns until a specified end date. This specified end date would be the same date throughout the entire table. In this example, let's make the specified end date 2023-12-31. My end goal is for the table to appear similar to the below. Please note since this is an example, I didn't include every row as to avoid having hundreds of rows listed below.

| next_generation_date | procedure | interval | frequency |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-17 00:00:00.000 | Clean Restroom | 1 | day |
| 2021-01-18 00:00:00.000 | Clean Restroom | 1 | day |
| 2021-01-19 00:00:00.000 | Clean Restroom | 1 | day |
| 2021-01-20 00:00:00.000 | Clean Restroom | 1 | day |
| 2021-01-17 00:00:00.000 | Vacuum | 2 | week |
| 2021-01-31 00:00:00.000 | Vacuum | 2 | week |
| 2021-02-14 00:00:00.000 | Vacuum | 2 | week |
| 2021-02-28 00:00:00.000 | Vacuum | 2 | week |
| 2021-02-01 00:00:00.000 | Inspect Fire Extinguisher | 3 | month |
| 2021-05-01 00:00:00.000 | Inspect Fire Extinguisher | 3 | month |
| 2021-08-01 00:00:00.000 | Inspect Fire Extinguisher | 3 | month |
| 2021-11-01 00:00:00.000 | Inspect Fire Extinguisher | 3 | month |
| 2021-10-01 00:00:00.000 | Test Generator | 1 | year |
| 2022-10-01 00:00:00.000 | Test Generator | 1 | year |
| 2023-10-01 00:00:00.000 | Test Generator | 1 | year |

Below is my most recent attempt in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio but when I execute the code, I'm presented with the following message: "*Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <=, >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression*".

```
DECLARE @EndDate AS DATE = '2023-12-31'

SELECT [procedure], [frequency], [interval], [next_generation_date] FROM [data].[table]

WHILE (@EndDate > (SELECT [next_generation_date] FROM [data].[table]))

IF (SELECT [frequency] FROM [data].[table]) = 'day'
       BEGIN
             SELECT DATEADD(day, (SELECT [interval] FROM [data].[table]), (SELECT [next_generation_date] FROM [data].[table]))
       END
ELSE IF (SELECT [frequency] FROM [data].[table]) = 'week'
       BEGIN
             SELECT DATEADD(week, (SELECT [interval] FROM [data].[table]), (SELECT [next_generation_date] FROM [data].[table]))
       END
ELSE IF (SELECT [frequency] FROM [data].[table]) = 'month'
       BEGIN
             SELECT DATEADD(month, (SELECT [interval] FROM [data].[table]), (SELECT [next_generation_date] FROM [data].[table]))
       END
ELSE IF (SELECT [frequency] FROM [data].[table]) = 'year'
       BEGIN
             SELECT DATEADD(year, (SELECT [interval] FROM [data].[table]), (SELECT [next_generation_date] FROM [data].[table]))
       END
```

Any and all suggestions are greatly appreciated as I'm new to SQL. Thank you.

Comment: What's your database management system? Oracle? SQL Server? PostgreSQL? Vertica? Add a matching tag to your question. Each of them has a different, handy, way to solve that without a stored procedure.

Comment: @marcothesane The database management system is SQL Server. I've updated the post with the tag.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a helper table that contains many integers, first.

```
CREATE TABLE many_integers (idx INT);
WITH units(units) AS (
SELECT 0 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION 
SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9
)
,tens             AS(SELECT units *        10 AS tens             FROM units       )
,hundreds         AS(SELECT tens  *        10 AS hundreds         FROM tens        )
,thousands        AS(SELECT hundreds *     10 AS thousands        FROM hundreds    )
,tenthousands     AS(SELECT thousands *    10 AS tenthousands     FROM thousands   )
,hundredthousands AS(SELECT tenthousands * 10 AS hundredthousands FROM tenthousands)                                                                                                                                        
INSERT                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
INTO many_integers
SELECT  hundredthousands +tenthousands +thousands +hundreds +tens +units 
FROM       units 
CROSS JOIN tens 
CROSS JOIN hundreds 
CROSS JOIN thousands 
CROSS JOIN tenthousands 
CROSS JOIN hundredthousands ;
```

Then cross join my in-data table with that `many_integers` table:

````
-- your input data, don't use in real query ...
WITH
indata(next_generation_date,proced,interv,frequency) AS (
          SELECT  '2021-01-17 00:00:00.000','Clean Restroom'           ,1,'day'
UNION ALL SELECT  '2021-01-17 00:00:00.000','Vacuum'                   ,2,'week'
UNION ALL SELECT  '2021-02-01 00:00:00.000','Inspect Fire Extinguisher',3,'month'
UNION ALL SELECT  '2021-10-01 00:00:00.000','Test Generator'           ,1,'year'
)
-- end of your input data - real query starts here ...
SELECT 
  CASE frequency
    WHEN 'day'   THEN  DATEADD( day   , idx , next_generation_date)
    WHEN 'week'  THEN  DATEADD( week  , idx , next_generation_date)
    WHEN 'month' THEN  DATEADD( month , idx , next_generation_date)
    WHEN 'year'  THEN  DATEADD( year  , idx , next_generation_date)
  END AS next_generation_date
, proced
, interv
, frequency
FROM indata CROSS JOIN many_integers
WHERE idx < 5000
 AND
  CASE frequency
    WHEN 'day'   THEN  DATEADD( day   , idx , next_generation_date)
    WHEN 'week'  THEN  DATEADD( week  , idx , next_generation_date)
    WHEN 'month' THEN  DATEADD( month , idx , next_generation_date)
    WHEN 'year'  THEN  DATEADD( year  , idx , next_generation_date)
  END <=  '2023-12-31 00:00:00'
ORDER BY 1
;                  ```
````

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Again, I'm new to SQL so I have a few questions regarding your provided code above. If my data set already contains a column of integers (the **interval** column), what is the reason for creating the helper table? Also, how can I replace the manually entered columns/rows that are included in your example (inside the WITH and SELECT syntax) and refer to the entire column(s) found within my data set instead?

Comment: you want to add zero, then one, then two, then three, then four, etc. days/weeks/months/years to your initial date. The changing integer comes from a `CROSS JOIN` of your base table with the series of integers; the same in row is joined with 0 , and adds e.g 0 days, then with 1, and adds 1 day, and so on. And yes, the full select I call `indata` is just your initial input, and would not be part of the real query. Use the real table instead of `indata` in the main query. I annotated the query in my response above accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for annotating and providing the explanations. When I tested and used your code, I noticed all of the procedures increased by a value of one, regardless of the numerical value found in the **interval** column.